# Exclude zero values from a C3.js bar chart

Tags: c3.js

Let's take for example following chart http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar.html
but replace columns data with the data below:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 0, 100, 0, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 0, 140, 200, 0, 50]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
        // or
        //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data3', 130, -150, 200, 300, -200, 100]
        ]
    });
}, 1000);
```

As we see we have a lot of white space or ZERO value bars, how can we remove it and remove white space. (not hide, I know how to hide it with CSS)

[Image example, what should be removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCfGW.png)

Comment: do you really want to have different spaces between x-ticks? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469937/c3js-timeseries-x-values-not-evenly-spaced?rq=1)

Comment: Me not, but client do want :)

Comment: did >[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29450998/735725)< help?

Comment: Seems that it doesn't help me, I need to make some changes on CHART BAR not with axis

Comment: hope you ll find your way through it man! this thing looks to me one of those client problems that you cant promise nor say its impossible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as googled in https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/81 
you need replace 0 to 'null' and add this:

```
    line: {
     connectNull: true,
    },

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, null, 100, null, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, null, 140, 200, null, 50]
        ],
        line: {
         connectNull: true,
        },
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
        // or
        //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data3', 130, -150, 200, 300, -200, 100]
        ]
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I only used null in data and it worked. I did not use connectNull: true. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
line: {
     connectNull: true,
    }
```

in your c3.generate block. 
It will connect all points/bars/... on the chart with a zero value in between.
It works with `null` as well as with `0`.